# What kind of data I can log with google firebase analytics with android application?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

What kind of data I can log with google firebase analytics with android application?

For example, in the search method, is it possible to report the searched words?And can I compare them? or counting the each word?

```
        Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent (
            Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.EventSearch,
            new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter[] {
                new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter (
                    Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.ParameterSearchTerm, termText),
            }
        );
```

I used the DebugView panel and the my data was sent, but where are they stored?

Or can I use this code for store my user ID's with log event?

```
FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("progress", "userid" ,SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after try and try, I found if We add new parameter in firebase console, that take 24 hours to take effective from application , but we can see the sent data in DebugView .

link: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en